Are there non-trivial endomorphisms of the Matrix algebra that are not inner automorphisms?
Let us consider the algebra of complex matrices $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.
An algebra endomorphism is a function $f:M_n(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{C})$ that is linear and preserve multiplication ($f(AB)=f(A)f(B)$). An inner automorphism is an algebra endomorphism $f$ such that there is $P\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ invertible such that $f(X)=P^{-1} X P$
I have seen that all algebra automorphisms of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ are inner automorphism. Furthermore, the null endomorphism (assigning to each matrix the matrix with only zeros) is an example of a (non-bijective) endomorphism that is not an inner automorphism.
But I cannot  find the answer to whether it is the only one: are there (necessarily non bijective) non-trivial endomorphisms of the Matrix algebra that are not inner automorphism?
Bonus question: what is the case for fields other than $\mathbb{C}$?

To exclude the zero endomorphism, one may require that $f(I)=I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Multiplication by a central idempotent other than $1$ is a nonunital endomorphism, but unfortunately, the only central idempotents in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ are the zero matrix and the identity matrix. Multiplying by a noncentral idempotent on either side (left or right) will not give a nonunital endomorphism.

See the references here.

There are none, and the result is true for any field. Indeed, any $M_n(F)$ where $F$ is a field is simple. For, assume $I$ is a nonzero ideal and $a \in I$ is a nonzero element, then $a_{kl} \neq 0$ for some $k,l$. But then $\frac{1}{a_{kl}} e_{ik}ae_{lj} = e_{ij} \in I$, so $I = M_n(F)$. Thus, any endomorphism $M_n(F) \to M_n(F)$ is either trivial, or injective. If it is injective, then dimension considerations force it to be surjective as well, whence it is an automorphism. Any automorphism of $M_n(F)$ is inner, which is a consequence of Skolem–Noether theorem.

There is no trivial endomorphism! Ring homomorphisms have to preserve the multiplicative identity.

@QiaochuYuan I mean, I would say it’s a matter of convention. The OP specifically defined in their post that “an algebra homomorphism is a function… that is linear and preserves multiplication”, so the zero map is certainly an endomorphism in that sense. It’s not an endomorphism in the category of unital algebras with unital homomorphisms, nor in the category of rings with ring homomorphisms, that’s certainly true. But if the category is (not necessarily unital) algebras with (not necessarily unital) homomorphisms or rngs with rng homomorphisms, I don’t see any issue.
